# Combining abstract model class and multi-table inheritance in Django

Tags: python, django, multiple-inheritance

I have three model classes:

`django.contrib.auth.models.User`, reffered to as `User`

`mysite.models.Profile`, reffered to as `Profile`

`mysite.models.Subscriber`, reffered to as `Subscriber`

`Profile` inherits from `User` in a way that is [well described](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) in docs as a solution to add custom properties to `User` model without bothering with swappable models (which were only added in version 1.5).

While `Profile` and `Subscriber` are different objects, they do share some properties. Namely, I want to use custom primary key algorithm with both and override `save()` method in a similar way, so that code can be reused in accordance with DRY. Now, if both were plain model classes, that would be simple:

```
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    key = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save():
        ...

class Profile(BaseProfile):
   ...

class Subscriber(BaseProfile):
   ...
```

However, Profile already uses multi-table inheritance. I'm thinking of a way similar to this:

```
class BaseProfile(models.Model):
    key = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def save():
        ...

class Profile(BaseProfile, User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...

class Subscriber(BaseProfile):
   ...
```

Would that be possible? If so, what order of inheritance is needed in my case, so that both model fields and `save()` method are called in a correct way? Will Meta of both model class not get in conflict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you link to does not describe inheriting from User via multi-table inheritance. It does explain that you can link a 'profile' like object by using a OneToOneField. Try:

```
class Profile(BaseProfile):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
```

I suspect you don't actually want blank=True and null=True in there, however.

This approach does mean that your User objects will very likely not have the same primary keys as their corresponding Profile objects but this might well be OK for you.

Comment: Yes, that's okay and no, I do want blank=True and null=True :) What I wanted are User fields available on Profile objects, but seems like it doesn't go along with abstract model classes, so I resort to this solution.